# How to process second dimension of an Array based on similar first dimension value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write some php code to process the second dimension's value of an array based on similar values of the first dimension values.

Following is the sample output.

```
[0] => Array (
             [0] => 1
             [1] => 0.091238491238491
       )
[1] => Array (
             [0] => 2
             [1] => 0.2221793635487
       )
[2] => Array (
             [0] => 2
             [1] => 0.10662717512033
       )
[3] => Array (
             [0] => 4
             [1] => 0.44354338998346
       )
[4] => Array (
             [0] => 6
             [1] => 0.2248243559719
       )
[5] => Array (
             [0] => 6
             [1] => 0.31764705882353
       )
[6] => Array (
             [0] => 6
             [1] => 0.15764625384879
       )
[7] => Array (
             [0] => 6
             [1] => 0.19160083160083
       )
[8] => Array (
             [0] => 12
             [1] => 0.31054875069499
       )
[9] => Array (
             [0] => 12
             [1] => 0.10915034227918
       )
[10] => Array (
             [0] => 15
             [1] => 0.32915461266474
       )
 //...........goes to 46000 elements
```

Now what I want to do is, if the index 0 values of each array is similar then I want to add the index 1's value.
So for example, if 0 index values for 4 arrays are same , I want to add index 1 values of all 4 arrays. 
If there is a unique value on 0th index, dont add it with anything, simply store index 1's value and move on.

Thanks very much.
Ghanshyam

Comment: Please *format* that array. It's impossible to see what dimension is what...

Comment: @deceze done, now we can look at code :)

Comment: @deceze: please have a look at it now

Answer (score 2):

```
$added = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (isset($added[$item[0]])) {
        $added[$item[0]] += $item[1];
    } else {
        $added[$item[0]] = $item[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you checking if the values of the 0th index in all the array elements are same or not. If they are same, we have to add the corresponding 1st index values for those arrays. E.g.
[1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0.2221793635487 )
[2] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0.10662717512033 )
Here, we have to add [1][1] and [2][1] because [1][0] and [2][0] are same.

Comment: That's exactly what this is doing. It's using the `[0]` index as *the key* to another array.

Comment: $added[$item[0]] = $added[$item[0]] + $item[1];

This is giving me Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in <filename> on line <>

Is it because we are trying to add arrays?  $added[$item[0]] and $item[1] are arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
$p=0;
$temp =  $final_prod_ex[0][1];
for($x=0; $x<count($final_prod)-1; $x++){
    if($final_prod_ex[$x][0]==$final_prod_ex[$x+1][0]){
        $temp = $temp + $final_prod_ex[$x+1][1];
    }
    else{
        $ans[$p] = $temp."    ".$final_prod_ex[$x][0];
        $temp = $final_prod_ex[$x+1][1];
        $p++;
    }
}
```

Finally figured it out after a lot of thinking(I'm new to programming)...Array's name is $final_prod_ex. Comment on this if I can make it better. And sorry @deceze. I could not understand your solution. I know you were trying to give the value of one array as an index to another. But what the scenario is, that value isnt like 0,1,2,3,4.... Its like 1,3,5,6,7,10. We are missing numbers in between. Maybe I didnt understand your solution. Correct me if I am wrong.
Thanks for all the help.